# Flutter Form Binding with Riverpod

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I'm new to flutter and riverpod and I'm trying to achieve some basic form databinding using providers.

I have a model which represents the form being filled out and I have a notifier provider setup to provide the model to the Consumer.  However I cannot get the checkbox widget to rebuild when the value changes therefore it never actually shows up as checked.  Even though the underlying value in the form data is correct.

This is the code I'm working with:

```html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class MyFormData {
  String name;
  bool isSelected;

  MyFormData(
    this.name,
    this.isSelected
  );
}

class MyFormController extends Notifier<MyFormData>{

  @override
  MyFormData build() {
    return MyFormData("test", false);
  }

  bool get isSelected => state.isSelected;
  set isSelected(value) {
    state.isSelected = value;
    state = state;
  }
}

final myFormControllerProvider = NotifierProvider<MyFormController, MyFormData>(MyFormController.new);

void main() {
  runApp(const ProviderScope(child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}

class Home extends ConsumerWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final formData = ref.watch(myFormControllerProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("My Form")),
      body: Center(
        child: Card(
          child:Row(
            children: [
              Checkbox(
                value: formData.isSelected, 
                onChanged: (value) => ref.read(myFormControllerProvider.notifier).isSelected = value!),
              const Text('I am a Checkbox')
            ],
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I feel like this follows every 'sample tutorial' for checkbox binding I've found but I know I'm missing something.  Can anyone help identify what I've done wrong?